# Which editor (or plugin) makes a version control workflow feel most first-class?

Tags: editors, version-control

By "first class" I can just work by forking and merging my code willy-nilly, several times every minute, without ever thinking about the VCS....

I'm looking for an editor environment where the most common thing one does is fork!

Answer (score 2):

[Git branching and merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), and [Vim](http://www.vim.org) with [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) works well for me both from a personal coding standpoint, as well as in my enterprise (we branch a and merge a *lot*).